# How does one compare every object-entry of an array-item to entries of another object while keeping/remembering each comparison result?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, comparison, key-value

I have an array of 2 objects `[ { bg: 'a', o: 'c' }, {'hg': 'a2', 'oo': 'c3' }  ]` coming from a json file. And I want to compare each object in the array to another object that looks like this `{ fm: 'a', fh: 'b', o: 'a', fe: 'b', ft: 'a', fb: 'c', bg: 'f' }` to determine if this object has both sets of key/value pairs in either of the objects in the json array. How can I compare these objects?

Comment: You want the single object to be a superset of the union of the two objects in the array? Or you want to see if either of the objects in the array is a subset of the single object? Could you please add some sample data including the expected results in each case?

Comment: I want to see if either of the objects in the array is a subset of the single object. In the first json object I expect it to match the a key/value pair in the assets name. which is placed into an object like this after a little manipulation. ```{fm: 'a', fh: 'b', o: 'c', fe: 'b', ft: 'a', fb: 'c', bg: 'a' }```  I expect the second object not to watch any of the assets.

Comment: There is nothing like a JSON array or JSON object. JS data-structures can be provided and transferred/interchanged as [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) strings (see [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)). Such strings can be converted back into objects by a parse process like `JSON.parse`. Thus `JSON` stands for both, a JavaScript namespace with methods and a syntax for serializing data-structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach utilizes

- [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) in order to provide/access each of an object's key-value pair in its array/tuple form of `[key, value]`.
- [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in order to write for each array-item the boolean result of comparing every of its entries (key-value pairs) against an additionally provided object.
- [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) in order to retrieve the boolean value of comparing every of an array-item's entries (key-value pairs) against an additionally provided object.

```js
const sampleArr = [ { bg: 'a', o: 'c' }, {'hg': 'a2', 'oo': 'c3' } ];
const sampleObj = { fm: 'a', fh: 'b', o: 'a', fe: 'b', ft: 'a', fb: 'c', bg: 'f' };


console.log("### How `Object.entries` works ###");
console.log({
  sampleArr
});
console.log(
  "sampleArr[0] => Object.entries(sampleArr[0]) ...",
  sampleArr[0], " => ",  Object.entries(sampleArr[0])
);
console.log(
  "sampleArr[1] => Object.entries(sampleArr[1]) ...",
  sampleArr[1], " => ",  Object.entries(sampleArr[1])
);


console.log("### Comparison 1 with what was provided by the OP ###");
console.log(
  sampleArr
    // create a new array which for each ...
    .map(item => {
      // ... `sampleArr` item retrieves/maps whether ...
      return Object
        .entries(item)
        // ... every entry of such an item exists
        // as entry of another provided object.
        .every(([key, value]) => sampleObj[key] === value)
    })
);


sampleArr.push({ o: 'a', ft: 'a', fh: 'b' }); // will match     ... maps to `true` value.
sampleArr.push({ o: 'a', ft: 'X', fh: 'b' }); // will not match ... maps to `false` value.

console.log("### Comparison 2 after pushing two more items into `sampleArr` ###");
console.log({
  sampleArr
});
console.log(
  sampleArr
    // create a new array which for each ...
    .map(item => {
      // ... `sampleArr` item retrieves/maps whether ...
      return Object
        .entries(item)
        // ... every entry of such an item exists
        // as entry of another provided object.
        .every(([key, value]) => sampleObj[key] === value)
    })
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you this is extremely helpful.